# Report Viewer displaying a value in a textbox

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, report-viewer2010, .net-framework-version

How to make 1 value inside the database to be displayed in a textbox?

I make a select of an ID and then I need the name to be shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already have configured the DataSet and DataSource,just drag the value/field from the DataSet (listed in the Report Data) and drop it on your TextBox,it'll automatically change the Expression in the TextBox («Expr»).

Comment: On Report Data you have a button on the top that allows you to create a new DataSet.

Comment: the problem was i couldnt find the report data window, i already find it thanks for your help